# How to augment class declared but not exported on Typescript module

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

The `hubot` type definitions have the following class:

```
declare namespace Hubot {
    // ...

    class Message {
        user: User;
        text: string;
        id: string;
    }

    // ...
}

// Compatibility with CommonJS syntax exported by Hubot's CoffeeScript.
// tslint:disable-next-line export-just-namespace
export = Hubot;
export as namespace Hubot;
```

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/a6b283d1d43d8c7c82a4a4e22d0fc27c9964154c/types/hubot/index.d.ts#L18-L22

I want to augment the `Message` class from my code, inside a `hubot.d.ts` file I've written:

```
import * as hubot from 'hubot';

declare namespace Hubot {
  export class Message {
    mentions: string[]
  }
}
```

But it does not works:
[image]

The `hubot.d.ts` file is included in the code by having

```
  "files": ["types/custom/hubot.d.ts"]
```

In the `tsconfig.json` file.

What I'm missing? Any way to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`hubot.d.ts` should contain:

```
// This import serves no purpose except to make the file a module
// (so that the following statement is a module augmentation rather
// than a module declaration) and could be replaced with `export {}`.
import * as hubot from 'hubot';

declare module "hubot" {
  interface Message {
    mentions: string[]
  }
}
```

A [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) is needed to add declarations to the `hubot` module.  Since the `Hubot` namespace is assigned as the export of the module, any augmentations made to the module will target that namespace directly; writing another `namespace Hubot { ... }` in the augmentation would create a nested namespace, which isn't what you want.  Finally, declaring a class gives a "duplicate identifier" error, while declaring an interface is sufficient to add properties.